# rabbitmq throws the AmqpException: No method found for class [B

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

When I send a message to the RabbitMQ, then it throws a AmqpException for loop:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException

    : Listener method 'no match' threw exception
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:198) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:127) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1521) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1444) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1431) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1410) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:848) [spring-rabbit-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:832) [spring-rabbit-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78) [spring-rabbit-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1073) [spring-rabbit-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_152]
    Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: No method found for class [B
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.DelegatingInvocableHandler.getHandlerForPayload(DelegatingInvocableHandler.java:149) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.DelegatingInvocableHandler.invoke(DelegatingInvocableHandler.java:129) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:60) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:190) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
```

I tried to add class-level @RabbitListener but it didn't work

```
@Component
@RabbitListener(queues = "test", containerFactory="rabbitListenerContainerFactory")
public class ReceiverTwo {

    @RabbitHandler
    public void process(String message) {
        System.out.println("Receiver: " + message);
    }
}
```

The PRODUCER side :

```
@Test
public void publishTest() throws IOException {
    channel.exchangeDeclare("testExchange", "direct", true);
    channel.queueBind("many", "testExchange", "many");
    String message = "The test message";
    channel.basicPublish("testExchange", "test",null, message.getBytes());
}
```

The CONSUMER side :

```
@Component
@RabbitListener(queues = "test")
public class ReceiverTwo {
    @RabbitHandler
    public void process(String message) {
        System.out.println("Receiver: " + message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You send array of bytes and try to receive string.

Change `process(String message)` to `process(byte[] message)`.

Other option is to set

```
MessageProperties messageProperties = new MessageProperties();
messageProperties.setContentType(MessageProperties.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN);
messageProperties.setContentEncoding(this.defaultCharset);
```

and pass it to

```
channel.basicPublish("testExchange", "test", messageProperties, message.getBytes());
```

See `SimpleMessageConverter.createMessage` for reference.

Or you can use `RabbitTemplate` it will do it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and it worked well. And I found another solution: AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder builder = new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder().contentEncoding("UTF-8").contentType("text/plain");  channel.basicPublish("testExchange", "many",builder.build(), message.getBytes());

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have passed a different class to the publisher and expected a different class as listener.

Answer (score 0):

Odds enough, the code works for days, this problem suddenly appears, I don't know what's wrong, solved with just move @RabbitListener from class to method, along with @RabbitHandler.

Comment: To quote from a classic "Short Circuit": "Newton Crosby : It's a machine... It just runs programs." :) I had a similar situation but when I looked what's the difference, it turned out the clients that were sending messages were different. A Spring client worked fine while a Python client didn't have all message parameters set correctly, specifically: content_type='text/plain' and content_encoding='utf-8'