# RabbitMQ while consuming message i am getting No method found for class [B Exception

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, jms, spring-jms, spring-rabbit

-> this is first time i am trying JMS, I Have created on consumer class to consume message from rabbitMQ GUI.
-> but when i am publishing any message from rabbitMQ GUI its giving error class not found. and continuously error is printing on console.

```java
@Component
@RabbitListener(queues =  {"#{addNeRangeQueue.name}"})
public class consumerController {

    @RabbitHandler
    public void receive(String message) {
        System.out.println("rabbit mq listener receive : "+message);
    }
}

   
   
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConsumerConfig {
 
    //properties value configuration i have removed here.
    @Bean
    public Queue addNeRangeQueue() {
        return new Queue(queueName,false);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public TopicExchange getTopicEchangeName() {
        return new TopicExchange(exchange);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding bindaddNeRange(TopicExchange getTopicEchangeName, Queue addNeRangeQueue) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(addNeRangeQueue).to(getTopicEchangeName).with(routingkey);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
    2020-09-08 00:19:10.378  WARN 9456 --- [ntContainer#0-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.
    
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1705) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1595) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1510) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1489) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1433) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:970) [spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:916) [spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83) [spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1291) [spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1197) [spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_211]
    Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: No method found for class [B
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.DelegatingInvocableHandler.getHandlerForPayload(DelegatingInvocableHandler.java:151) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.DelegatingInvocableHandler.getMethodFor(DelegatingInvocableHandler.java:270) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.getMethodFor(HandlerAdapter.java:84) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandlerAndProcessResult(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:146) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:133) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1591) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54457496

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rabbitmq throws the AmqpException: No method found for class \[B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54457496/rabbitmq-throws-the-amqpexception-no-method-found-for-class-b)

Answer (score 1):

You need to show your container factory configuration. If you are using the JSON message converter, it will return `byte[]` if the content_type property is wrong.

When sending from the UI, set `content_type=application/json`.

If you are using the default converter, set `content_type=text/plain` to convert `byte[]` to String.

Comment: can you please give me code example so i can go through that.

Comment: You said you were sending the message from the UI - if so, you can set the `content_type` property before sending. See `Properties` in the `Publish Message` section.